# Why when I try to modify a list via a negative index slice it just adds objects

Tags: python, list, slice

My list is

```
ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

Why when I  try to modify a list via a negative index slice it just adds objects.

```
ls[-1:-3] = [10,10,10]
```

The result is

```
[1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 10, 10, 5]
```

But it should be  this way

```
[1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 10 ]
```

Comment: "But it should be this way" why do you think *it should*?

Comment: Do you want to produce this [1, 2, 3, 10, 10, 10 ] output or you want to  modify a list via a negative index  ?

Comment: It inserts also using positive slices (`ls[1:1] = [10,10,10]`). What's the problem? That's the design.

Comment: if you want to do that, you should do `ls[-2:] = [10,10,10]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You might want to take a look at [this](https://railsware.com/blog/python-for-machine-learning-indexing-and-slicing-for-lists-tuples-strings-and-other-sequential-types/) source. There are different ways of slicing and replacing arrays. What you want, negative slicing and then replacing, can be done like this:

```
ls = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
ls[-3:-1] = [10, 10, 10]
>> [1, 2, 10, 10, 10, 5]
```

Note that you should index with `[-3:-1]` instead of `[-1:-3]` to get the slicing you want. `[-3:-1]` returns `[3,4]`, whereas `[-1:-3]` returns `[]`.

Answer (score 0):

1st way:

```
def test_new_ls():
  ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
  ls[3:5] = [10,10,10] 
  print(ls)

test_new_ls()
```

2nd way:

```
def test_new_ls():
 ls = [1,2,3,4,5]
 #ls[3:5] = [10,10,10]
 ls[-2:] = [10,10,10] 
 print(ls)
test_new_ls()
```

[image: Output]

Comment: I don't think this is useful to OP since OP is referring to _negative indexing_.

Comment: Same thing can be achieved using ls[-2:] = [10,10,10]

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes:

1. In slice `[start:end]`, `start` shoule not be larger than `end`. `ls[-3:-1]` is recommended.
2. In slice `[start:end]`, the element at index `end` is not included.
   `ls[-3:-1]` means: `ls[-3]` and `ls[-2]`, but no `ls[-1]`.